# trying to display the name of a employee supervisor in a single table

Tags: mysql, database

here is my database

```
Drop Table Staff;

Create Table Staff
(StaffNo  varchar(6) Primary Key,
Lastname  varchar(30),
Firstname varchar(25),
Hire_date  date,
Location  varchar(30),
SupervisorNo  varchar(6),
Salary  numeric(8,2),
Commission  numeric(4,2));

-- Populate Staff Table ------------------------------------------

Insert Into Staff
Values('000001','Zambini','Rick',Date('1980-2-15'),'LOS 
ANGELES','000000',6000.00,5.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000003','Vidoni','Cheryl',Date('1980-3-6'),'NEW 
YORK','000000',5780.00,5.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000004','Coudray','Sandy',Date('1980-6-6'),'LOS 
ANGELES','000001',6237.00,5.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000006','Thomas','Pat',Date('1991-1-8'),'NEW 
YORK','000003',5875.00,5.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000008','McLester','Debbie',Date('1981-4-12'),'LOS 
ANGELES','000001',4792.00,5.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000011','Michaels','Delores',Date('1982-5-
5'),'CHICAGO','000012',4927.00,7.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000012','Charles','Ted',Date('1983-2-
2'),'CHICAGO','000000',5945.00,5.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000013','Marin','Mark',Date('1983-6-5'),'LOS 
ANGELES','000001',4802.00,11.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000015','Roddick','Mary',Date('1984-2-13'),'NEW 
YORK','000003',5493.00,8.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000016','Long','Nicole',Date('1984-8-18'),'NEW 
YORK','000003',5190.00,7.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000019','Rolfes','Chuck',Date('1984-9-9'),'LOS 
ANGELES','000001',4586.00,6.00);
Insert Into Staff
Values('000020','Sanders','Kathy',Date('1985-3-
23'),'CHICAGO','000012',3783.00,5.00);

COMMIT;
```

I have to display the supervisor name of McLester but  i can't find a way to correlate the supervisorNo to a Lastname

this one a has me really stumped

i cant do a join because this is one table and i cant find a way to link supervisorno to the lastname value without looking up the answer in the data

```
select *
from staff
where  supervisorno in (select supervisorno from staff) and lastname = 
'mclester';
```

my query so far

Comment: Are you saying `McLester` is a supervisor?

Comment: sorry been coding for a while and brain is mush i need to find McLester's supervisor name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like `SELECT * FROM staff where staffno = (SELECT supervisorno FROM staff WHERE lastname = 'mclester');` work?

I know it's not pretty, but I think it should work.

Comment: yess it worked perfectly,  thanks you I was beating my head in with this one. Ah i see i was getting stuck because i didn't know if matching the staffno with supervisorno would work to connect the data

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from staff where StaffNo  IN (select SupervisorNo from staff where Lastname = 'McLester');
```